# Why all parts are italic like the subscript?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

Based on the added picture, I have written `SK$_{i,GID}$` and expected that "SK" should no be italic but it did. How can I prevent "SK" to be italic? I want that just "i" from the subscript part be italic, not other parts.

[image]

Comment: Hello, please provide more Code. An MWE would be nice. Because when i test this, it works as you expect it. So there is something more to this, which is not shown here. Especially since there is a box around the text, there reason might be the box...

Comment: You can also use `SK\textsubscript{i,GID}`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\fbox{SK$_{i,\mathrm{GID}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `\text` might be dangerous here, since it will inherit the font of the surrounding text. `\mathrm` is safer.

Comment: @campa Thank you for noticing this. I'm going to edit my answer to include your recommendation.